# Is there another "wave" function that isn't a combination of sines?

Tags: functions, trigonometry, continuity

I have been wondering about the reasons trigonometric functions are the ones which we typically use to describe waves.

I thought of the following conditions that we would want a wave function $f: \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ to satisfy:

1. $f(x)$ is continuously differentiable over $\mathbb{R}$.
2. $f(x)$ is periodic, i.e, for some $p\in \mathbb{R}$, $f(x+p)=f(x)$ is true for all $x\in \mathbb{R}$.
3. $f(x)$ is symmetrical around its extremums, meaning that if $s\in \mathbb{R}$ maximizes or minimizes $f(x)$, then $f(x-s)=f(s-x)$ for all $x\in \mathbb{R}$.
4. $f(x)$ oscillates above and below the $x$-axis in a symmetrical way. Meaning, given $f(x)$ has a period $p$, then $f(x+\frac{p}{2})=-f(x)$.

I am not sure if these are good conditions, but my question is as follows:

Do we know about functions other than $\sin (x)$ and any finite combinations of powers or linear combinations of functions $\sin (tx)$ that can satisfy these conditions?
For example, $3\cos(2x) = 3\sqrt{1-\sin^2(2x)}$ isn't a good function.

I appreciate any answers or help.

Comment: Of course it's possible to construct a periodic function which resembles the sine wave. For example, using quadratics with alternating signs of the leading coefficient. The thing is, any such function can be approximated using Fourier series which is a combination of sines so what exactly is your reasoning for constructing a special function?

Comment: I metioned that the combination of sines must be finite... I don't have a specific use for this, I am simply curious if these are special characteristics of the sine function.

Comment: @HappyDay One important special property of the set of sine and cosine function $\{\sin(x),\cos(x),\sin(2x),\cos(2x),\dots\}$, is that they are mutually orthogonal in the function space $L^2([0,2\pi])$. That is, for any pair $f_1 \neq f_2$ from this set, we have $\int_0^{2 \pi} f_1(x)f_2(x)\,dx = 0$.

Comment: I bet that the Jacobi elliptic sine $\text{sn}(\cdot, k)$ satisfies all properties for all $k>0$. Plot: https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?key=&i=Plot%5BSn%5Bx%2C+4%5D%2C+%7Bx%2C+-10%2C+10%7D%5D

Comment: @HappyDay One function that satisfies these properties except for differentiability is the [triangle wave function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Triangle_wave). We could make this function differentiable by "smoothing it out" around its extrema.

Comment: Many, many functions satisfy these requirements. Especially the first requirement is unnecessarily lax - you might want to require smoothness. The triangle wave function as @BenGrossmann mentioned works if you move it a bit to satisfy the oscillation requirement (4), and replacing the linear part with quadratic, cubic, etc. parts, you get many families of functions satisfying these requirements.

Comment: @HappyDay A function that satisfies all the requirements is the [Clausen function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clausen_function)

Comment: @SomeCallMeTim With a judicious use of a [bump function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bump_function), even infinite differentiability isn't an obstacle.

Comment: @BenGrossmann indeed. Note that the Clausen function doesn't work, as it is not symmetric around its extrema (requirement 3).

Comment: @SomeCallMeTim Good catch

Comment: Thanks very much! I was looking for a function that is never a straight line, so the elliptic sine function mentioned above is a great answer.

Comment: You could stitch together cubic splines.